# Can UIView and UIImagView implement touch events simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In the UIView, there is several sub views of UIImageView objects.

Since I need to detect the touch events from the UIImageView and from the remaining area of the UIView.

Can I implement touch events in UIView and UIImagView simultaneously ?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of touch events are you expecting on the view and on the imageView?

Comment: Just simple touch up inside event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you should consider gesture recognizers. Use the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to identify and respond to taps on a view.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;

tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnView:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[view addGesture:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

...

tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnImage:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[imageView addGesture:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

...
```

define `-(void)handleTapOnView:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture` and `-(void)handleTapOnImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture`and handle the touches there.

There are other kinds of gestures too. You can read more about them [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1).